# Change the definition of an Index with Expression without dropping/recreating the index

Tags: postgresql, database-internals, postgresql-12

I'm in a peculiar situation:

I have multiple indexes with expressions that use a function. I want to switch them to a different function, where I can guarantee the function behaves the same (so the indexed values will not be invalid). Ideally, I don't want to drop the existing index and re-index them, because this requires more development overhead.

I can see in the `pg_index` table, there is an `indexprs` column, which contains the "internal" definition of an index (the `pg_indexes` table is a pretty-print version of this). Specifically, I think I identified the relevant indexes to have a format along the lines of `({FUNCEXPR :funcid 870 :funcresulttype 25 :funcretset false`...

Backtracking that `funcid 870` into the `information_schema.routines`, I was able to correlate it on the `specific_name` (which contains this funcid) and was able to determine that it is indeed the specific function that I want to change.

Would it - theoretically - be possible to replace this funcid with the new funcid and the indexes would then refer to the new function? How would I do so, since this column is of type pg_node_tree? If not, is there a way to achieve my goal in a non-hacky way?

addendum: I will probably still do this the "clean" way unless there's a proven safe way to do this, but this has piqued my interest enough to ask a question about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do it right, that would work, but I also wouldn't do it that way.

But that is not enough: PostgreSQL also keeps track of the dependency between the index and the function by entries in `pg_depend`, so you would have to modify the respective entry as well. Otherwise you'd get interesting error messages when you try to drop the index. If the `oid` 870 happens to get reused for a different function later on, you could also get other interesting ways of data corruption.